# Table Outer Join using SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to join couple of table to achieve the results as below

```
Table 1 
Table1.Counter  Table1.EFFCT From
9999    17/02/2014
9998    17/02/2014
9997    29/03/2014
9996    28/05/2014
9995    16/08/2014
9994    25/09/2014
9993    24/11/2014
9992    12/02/2015

Table 2
Table2.Counter  Table2.EFFCT From   Table2.EffectTo
9999    17/02/2014  16/02/2014
9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9992    20/03/2014  1/01/9999

Expected output
Table1.Counter  Table1.EFFCT From   Table2.Counter  Table2.EFFCT From   Table2.EffectTo
9999    17/02/2014  9999    17/02/2014  16/02/2014
9998    17/02/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9997    29/03/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9996    28/05/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9995    16/08/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9994    25/09/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9993    24/11/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9992    12/02/2015  9992    20/03/2014  1/01/9999
```

I have tried the following code(without OR) but it provides null for certain rows

```
select Table1.Counter, 
Table1.EFFCT_From, 
Table2.Counter, 
Table2.EFFCT_From,
Table2.EffectTo
From Table1
left outer join Table2
on (Table1.Counter = Table2.Counter and Table1.EFFCT_From = Table2.EFFCT_From) 
OR (Table1.EFFCT_From = Table2.EFFCT_From and Table1.Counter < Table2.Counter )
Order by Table1.Counter;
```

Is here a way to join two tables in these circumstances

I am getting the following results when I join hem without OR.

```
Table1.Counter  Table1.EFFCT From   Table2.Counter  Table2.EFFCT From   Table2.EffectTo
9999    17/02/2014  9999    17/02/2014  16/02/2014
9998    17/02/2014  9998    17/02/2014  19/03/2014
9997    29/03/2014  Null    Null    Null
9996    28/05/2014  Null    Null    Null
9995    16/08/2014  Null    Null    Null
9994    25/09/2014  Null    Null    Null
9993    24/11/2014  Null    Null    Null
9992    12/02/2015  9992    20/03/2014  1/01/9999
```

OR Statement is my failed attempt o get what I am after

Comment: Why shouldn't include `NULL`s when you are doing an `OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @PM77-1 -- looks like OP is wanting a running total of the previous values...

Comment: Can you show us what the actual results are (ie which rows get the NULLS)?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Some make this easier than others...

Comment: I think you're wanting a between test in the first half of the OR'd predicate. You've got an equality check that doesn't match up with expected output.

Comment: What's expected output when there's no row with `Counter = 9999` in `Table 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is working exactly as expected.

An outer join is:
"All the rows from both tables, and joined together if there is a match on the join-conditions... if not, it will show nulls."

You do not have a row in table 2 for: 9997, 9996, 9995, 9994 or 9993
So those rows will not be matched against a row in table2 and will show NULLs instead.

I don't think I've ever seen somebody try to use an OR in the join-conditions... so I can't comment on whether that really should work, but I suspect it just doesn't (if it does, feel free to show me the documentation explaining it, I'd like to learn).

Reading up it looks like a join-condition works just like a boolean operator... in this case - it might be failing because multiple rows match the OR-condition

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question itself, but you can put any logical expression in the `ON` part of the `JOIN`. Any expression that can be in the `WHERE` can be put in `JOIN`. Whether that would bring expected result or not is a different matter, but the query would be valid.

Comment: yeah that's pretty neat - I'd never seen it before, so I've definitely learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output shows the result of an inner join, not outer. You want every row from Table1 to match with *something* from Table2.

One way is to generate an intermediate result set. You don't specify the DBMS (tsk, tsk) so I can't tell if it has CTE capability, but most do so this is what you get.

The intermediate result set contains a list of Counter values that have a match between the two tables. Now just join the tables using the intermediate to specify the Counter value that completes the join. See the output <kbd>[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/766d5/4/0)</kbd>

```
with
Matches( Counter )as(
    select  t1.Counter
    from    Table1  t1
    join    Table2  t2
        on  t2.Counter = T1.Counter
)
select  t1.Counter T1_Counter, t1.EFFCT_From T1_EFFCT_From,
        t2.Counter T2_Counter, t2.EFFCT_From T2_EFFCT_From, t2.EffectTo T2_EffectTo
from    Table1  t1
join    Table2  t2
    on  t2.Counter =(
        select  Min( Counter )
        from    Matches
        where   Counter >= t1.Counter )
order by t1.Counter desc;
```

The key is the subquery which returns the Counter value, if there is a match, or the lowest previous matched value.